# How to refresh a table with AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I have an input and a div on this test website. I'm trying to use Ajax to send the value of that input to my PHP script then filter a table with that input and then show it on the page without refreshing.

I looked up how to do this but every time I couldn't make it work.
Or the table didn't show up and when it showed up the Ajax post value didn't go to my PHP script.

Right now the table shows up but the value is not sent to the php script giving me this error:"Notice: Undefined index: search in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\AJAX tries\atualiza.php on line 4"

HTML input table

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>AJAX!</div>
    <form action="" name="form">
        <input onkeyup="ichooseyouajax(this.value);" name="search">
    </form>
    <div id="search_results">

    </div>

</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='JS/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ichooseyouajax(str){
    if (str.lenght==0) {

}else{
          $.post('atualiza.php', {'search': str}, function() {
            $('#search_results').load('atualiza.php').show();
    }); 
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

PHP SCRIPT

```
<?php 
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "intranet_db");

    $search=$_POST["search"];

    $selecionar=mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM stock WHERE id='$search' OR nome LIKE '%$search%'");
    echo"<table>";
    while ($linha=mysqli_fetch_array($selecionar)) {
        echo"
        <tr>
            <td>".$linha['id']."</td>
            <td>".$linha['nome']."</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
    echo"</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with following.

```
    $.post('atualiza.php', {'search': str}, function() {
        $('#search_results').load('atualiza.php').show();
    });
```

with

```
$.post('atualiza.php', {'search': str}, function(response) {
    $('#search_results').html(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it :D

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $.post('atualiza.php', {'search': str}, function() {
> ```

This makes a POST request to the URL.

When it gets a response, you say:

> ```
> $('#search_results').load('atualiza.php').show();
> ```

This makes a *separate* GET request to the URL.

Since the GET request doesn't have the data in it, `$_POST['search']` is undefined.

---

Don't make a second HTTP request. Use the data returned from the first request.

```
$.post('atualiza.php', {'search': str}, function(data) {
    console.log(data); // Replace this with code to update the DOM
});
```

Comment: Most tutorials and answers don't explain that thanks.